# span textContent not getting updated

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I am trying to update the text of span element from stimulus controller. The event will be fired on data action.

```
_updateSelectedDealTitle(replace_text){
    const ele = document.getElementById('deal_title');
    ele.textContent = replace_text;
  }
```

With this text is not getting updated.
I tried innerText, innerHTML too. Still it´s not updating.

Comment: Also add more code like `html` posted code isn't enough for debugging the problem.

Comment: If all this does not work. your `ele` Element is probably empty/does not exist. You can just print it to the console to check if the ele variable has any contents.